# How to display error message in the view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my symfony2 app I created custom error page that i placed in directory

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception.
```

So i have my error404.html.twig file, which has nothing in it except reference to my layout. Now the question is, if i throw an error in the controller, like this:

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User with this id.');
```

How can i display this message on the screen? Do I have to somehow pass it into the view?

Comment: Yes. The view needs to iterate an array of data and examine the data within this array.

Comment: ok, but which array, or how can i pass it? Could you give me an example? answer maybe?;)

Answer (score 1):

Couple minutes of search let me found that Symfony default ExceptionController passes 'exception' variable into the view. So all there is to be done here is:

```
{{exception.message}}
```